# How to execute install4j Background updater immediately

Tags: java, install4j

I tried the sample code from HelloGui provided with install4j8.0.2 to download the update of my application using **Background update downloader**. When the download is completed I want to show a confirm dialog to the user whether they want to run the updater now or later. The problem is the updater is not execute immediately, rather it is scheduled for the next time the launcher will run.

In summary, my requirement is:

1. Update the download in background
2. Show a confirmation dialog when download is complete
3. Execute the updater immediately if the user wants to update now.

I cannot accomplish this as the updater is scheduled to be executed on next run of the launcher.

I see that `UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()` returns false when the download finishes.

Here is the sample code to execute updater immediately:

```
    private void downloadAndUpdate() {
        // Here the background update downloader is launched in the background
        // See checkForUpdate(), where the interactive updater is launched for comments on launching an update downloader.
        new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // Note the third argument which makes the call to the background updater blocking.
                ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("1160", null, true, null);
                // At this point the update downloader has returned and we can check if the "Schedule update installation"
                // action has registered an update installer for execution
                // We now switch to the EDT in done() for terminating the application
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    get(); // rethrow exceptions that occurred in doInBackground() wrapped in an ExecutionException
                    if (UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Download is complete, the new version will now be installed.", "Hello",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        // We execute the update immediately, but you could ask the user whether the update should be
                        // installed now. The scheduling of update installers is persistent, so this will also work
                        // after a restart of the launcher.
                        executeUpdate();
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update could not be downloaded", "Hello", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error has occurred:" + e.getCause().getMessage(), "Hello", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

        }.execute();
    }

    private void executeUpdate() {
        // The arguments that are passed to the installer switch the default GUI mode to an unattended
        // mode with a progress bar. "-q" activates unattended mode, and "-splash Updating hello world ..."
        // shows a progress bar with the specified title.
        UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q", "-splash", "Updating ..."), true, null);
    }
```

Comment: It works for the "hello" sample project. What is different in your project? If `UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled() ` returns false the "Schedule update installation" action has not been called in the background update downloader.

Comment: @IngoKegel, "Schedule update installation" is in "Background update downloader" application under "Installer Action Group" as it should. Is there any programmatic way to set schedule update installation to **now** with the api?

Comment: That is what `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q", "-splash", "Updating ...")` does, based on an update that has been registered by the "Schedule update installation" action

Answer (score 0):

To execute the downloaded update (by Background update downloader) immediately:

1. Open a launcher
2. Go to **Executable info** || **Auto-update integration**
3. Select **Execute downloaded update installers at startup**

[image: install4 Auto-update integration]

If we execute downloader and update programmatically, still we need to select this; otherwise newly downloaded update does not run immediately. I have tested this with install4j version 8.0.2.